# How to send data to my database safely?

Tags: java, php, mysql

How can I send data to my database safely without any user forging?

Let's say, there's like 25 people using my application and I want to upload stats of their playing data.

I can't use JDBC because they could easily decompile and then get access to my database.

I was thinking of creating something in PHP but then they could easily update their values as well like http://mywebsite.com/update.php?user=x&gold=23

Any suggestions on a SAFE way of uploading stats without user forging?

Comment: whole lot of missing information to be able to answer this

Comment: Is the application and server one and the same? To reword, is the application on the server you need to interact with or is this a mobile application, etc?

Comment: @Dagon, what more do you need? I can provide it if you ask

Comment: @Jesse the application is not on the server. The application is on whoever is using it, it is a desktop program. I want to track stats of whoever is using it without them being able to forge fake data.

Comment: it it is  on their server, they can send back any data they want, you cant prevent that - so um don't host it there

Comment: Use a ReST API (as a middle-ware layer). Require that the user of the API authenticate to your server (where you might well choose Java and JDBC; or PHP) and then communicate with the database. It's the responsibility of the middle-ware layer to act as an intermediary to the database.

Comment: do a POST request with a secret key attached. verify the secret key on the server to ensure the request came from you

Comment: @sudo soul, can't they just decompile my program and find the secret key then?

Comment: background on the app would be helpful. is this a java application that the user will be running on their computer?

Comment: @sudo soul, yes it will be a program they will be running on their pc.